# Does ormlite support inheritance?

Tags: android, inheritance, ormlite

Does ormlite support this three inheritance-strategies?

- table per class hierarchy
- table per subclass
- table per concrete class

I found [this discussion on the ORMLite user group](http://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-dev/browse_thread/thread/53e2c4c4b401030b), but I'm not sure it answers my question.

Specially i want use "table per class hierarchy". If their isn't support from the ormlite framework i will make one class and forget the inheritance, but i would prefer to use inheritance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not support these automatically, no.  I'm not sure you actually read the thread you linked to because it's quite specific about it:

> > What I need is: If I have class A as a superclass, and I have direct subclasses B and C, and I run a query for all records/objects of class A, I do want to have all objects of class A, B and C returned.
>
> Yeah, ORMLite does not do this and currently I have no plans to support it.  The complexity of this, unless I am mistaken on how to accomplish this, is outside of what I'd say was "Lite".   The way Hibernate supports such constructs, is by having foreign keys, multiple tables, and magic joins.

That question gives some ideas about how to use ORMLite to implement inheritance:

> 1) You could have class A and an associated table -- so it can't be abstract.  Then you could have have B and C which subclass A and have all of As fields each in a separate table.  You could then create a special DAO for A which would also query for B and C and add them into your results for A.
>
> 2) Another way to do it is you could make classes B and C *not* be subclasses but instead have a foreign object to A.  You can then query all of the As and some of them would be B's A part and some C's A part and some just A.  You then could also query Bs and Cs and use the A DAO to refresh and get the A's fields you would not be able to cast.  A could also have some sort of enum which said whether it was a A, B, or C.  You could also do some magic where you could say getSubClassObject(), if would look at the enum and query the B or C dao for the associated object with the right foreign key for the A object.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i wasn't clear enough about the link. I thought maybe their is now a implemented solution for it, because the post is from January 2011, but thanks for your answer

Comment: Np @Flow.  That's another vote for that feature.  If you want to help add it to ORMLite, send some email on the mailing lists.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back, but does this mean that if Class B extends Class A, you cant have two different tables, where Class B uses Class A properties as table B columns?

Comment: That's correct @Max.  The fields from the Class A base class are in Class B's table.

Comment: ORMLite seemed very promising and I started using it in my project until I realized that it does not support inheritance mapping strategies. I needed table per concrete class strategy. Since the tool would have influenced my model class design I decided against using it and went with a traditional Android content provider with a simple custom DAO framework.

Comment: The "Lite" in OrmLite means it's not a full fledged ORM. If you need a full fledged ORM, feel free to port Hibernate to Android. Also, every tool influences your class model to a certain extent. We're not in an ideal world with ideal tools and ideal models.

Comment: I am agree with you @FarrukhNajmi : The "pojo's" model should not be impacted of DBMS matter. it's the purpose of an abstract layer between DBMS and business object.